# Layer Stack class to practice std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, stack, smart-pointers

The following three source files is to define and test a class `StackLayer`.

While it was written in a need for scalable layer-based architecture design, it was also a practice for `std::shared_ptr` (I'm new to C++11).

I'm not sure if I'm understanding the concept and best practices for `std::weak_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`.

You will notice that the `LayerNode` `struct` is completely `public` to derived classes, which I couldn't avoid because of some error `std::shared_ptr` was complaining about ("conversion exists but inaccessible").  I don't like this because it ruins all the encapsulation.

I'm also not sure if I have any memory leak or not (at least it is not breaking).

To prevent lower layer to access higher layer, I also had to make GetLayer function return null if that case happens. Should I assert or throw on this case instead of returning `nullptr`?

I only tested it in Visual C++ CPT120 (might have missing 'typename' errors in gcc, or not if I get lucky)

**Singleton.h**

```
template<typename Derived>
class Singleton
{
public:
    // Getter
    static Derived& GetInstance( void )
    {
        static Derived s_instance;
        return s_instance;
    }
protected:
    // Ctor
    Singleton( void ){}
    // Dtor
    virtual ~Singleton( void ){}
private:
    // NO COPY
    Singleton( const Singleton& rhs );
    // NO ASSIGNMNET
    Singleton& operator=( const Singleton& rhs );
}; // class Singleton
```

**LayerStack.h**

```
#ifndef LAYER_STACK_INCLUDE_GUARD
#define LAYER_STACK_INCLUDE_GUARD
#include "Singleton.h"      // Singleton
#include <vector>           // std::vector
#include <memory>           // std::shared_ptr std::weak_ptr std::dynamic_casting
#include <unordered_map>    // std::unordered_map
#include <cassert>          // assert
#include <type_traits>      // std::is_pointer
#include <algorithm>        // std::for_each
#include <functional>       // std::function

class LayerStack;

// public Inherit this class to make a layer.
// layer is to be added to an instance of LayerStack before calling GetLayer function.(Look at LayerStack::Push function)
template <typename Derived>
class Layer : public LayerStack::LayerNode, public Singleton<Derived>
{
    friend class LayerStack;

public:
    typedef Derived instance_type;
    Layer( void )
        : LayerNode( typeid(Derived).hash_code() )
        , Singleton()
    {
    }
    template <typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<T> GetLayer( void )
    {
        return LayerNode::m_pLayerStack->QueryLayerFrom<T>(m_attitue);
    } // std::shared_ptr<T> GetLayer( void )
    virtual ~Layer( void ) {}
}; // class Layer : public LayerStack::LayerNode, public Singleton<Derived>

// Layer Stack.
// Can store instance of layer inheriting class Layer.
// These rules are to be followred:
//      * Each type of layer can only appear once in the same layer stack.( Layer is Singleton. Look at Layer definition )
//      * Layer can access other layer by calling GetLayer function, but not in ascending order( Only layer pushed eairler than caller layer can be accessed. In other words, top layer can acess all layers, while bottom layer cannot access any layer)
class LayerStack
{
    template <typename Derived>
    friend class Layer;
private:
    typedef std::size_t type_hash_type;
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    struct LayerNode
    {
        LayerNode( type_hash_type typeHash )
            : m_pLayerStack(nullptr)
            , m_typeHash(typeHash)
            , m_attitue(0)
        {
        }
        virtual ~LayerNode( void ) {}
        LayerStack*                 m_pLayerStack;
        LayerStack::type_hash_type  m_typeHash;
        int                         m_attitue;
    };
public:
    typedef std::unordered_map<type_hash_type, std::weak_ptr<LayerNode>> layer_map_type;
    typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<LayerNode>> layer_vec_type;
private:
    layer_map_type m_layerMap;
    layer_vec_type m_layerVec;
public:
    LayerStack( void )
        : m_layerMap()
        , m_layerVec()
    {
    }
    template <typename T>
    void Push( std::shared_ptr<T>&& item )
    {
        static_assert(!std::is_pointer<T>::value, "Cannot use a shared pointer to a pointer");
        // Gets type hash code
        type_hash_type h = typeid(T).hash_code();
        // Search item by the hash code from the map.
        // item shouldn't be duplicate(Singleton)
        assert(m_layerMap.find(h) == m_layerMap.end());
        // Set Parent pointer
        item->m_pLayerStack = this;
        // Add item to the vector
        m_layerVec.push_back(item);
        // Add item to the map
        m_layerMap[h] = item;
        // Set attitue
        item->m_attitue = m_layerVec.size();
    } // void Push( std::shared_ptr<T>&& item )
    void Pop( void )
    {
        m_layerMap.erase(m_layerVec.back()->m_typeHash);
        m_layerVec.pop_back();
    } // void Pop( void )
    template <typename CAST_TYPE>
    void ForAscendingEach( std::function<void(CAST_TYPE*)> callback)
    {
        std::for_each( m_layerVec.begin(), m_layerVec.end(), [&]( std::shared_ptr<LayerNode> spNode )
        {
            callback(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<CAST_TYPE>(spNode).get());
        });
    }
    template <typename CAST_TYPE>
    void ForDescendingEach( std::function<void(CAST_TYPE*)> callback)
    {
        std::for_each( m_layerVec.rbegin(), m_layerVec.rend(), [&]( std::shared_ptr<LayerNode> spNode )
        {
            callback(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<CAST_TYPE>(spNode).get());
        });
    }
    template <typename CAST_TYPE, typename ...Args>
    void ForAscendingEach( void (CAST_TYPE::*callback)(Args...) , Args... args)
    {
        std::for_each( m_layerVec.begin(), m_layerVec.end(), [&]( std::shared_ptr<LayerNode> spNode )
        {
            (std::dynamic_pointer_cast<CAST_TYPE>(spNode).get()->*callback)(args...);
        });
    }
    template <typename CAST_TYPE, typename ...Args>
    void ForDescendingEach( void (CAST_TYPE::*callback)(Args...) , Args... args)
    {
        std::for_each( m_layerVec.rbegin(), m_layerVec.rend(), [&]( std::shared_ptr<LayerNode> spNode )
        {
            (std::dynamic_pointer_cast<CAST_TYPE>(spNode).get()->*callback)(args...);
        });
    }
    size_type Size( void )
    {
        return m_layerVec.size();
    } // size_type Size( void )
    template <typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<T> QueryLayer( void )
    {
        assert( m_layerMap.find(typeid(T).hash_code()) != m_layerMap.end() );

        return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(m_layerMap[typeid(T).hash_code()].lock());
    }
private:
    template <typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<T> QueryLayerFrom( int attitue )
    {
        assert( m_layerMap.find(typeid(T).hash_code()) != m_layerMap.end() );

        return m_layerMap[typeid(T).hash_code()].lock()->m_attitue < attitue
            ? std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(m_layerMap[typeid(T).hash_code()].lock())
            : nullptr; 
    }
}; // class LayerStack
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "LayerStack.h"
#include <iostream>

#define PROMPT(MSG) do { std::cout << " * " << (MSG) << std::endl; } while(0)
#define SHOW(EXPR) do { std::cout << (#EXPR) << " : " << (EXPR) << std::endl; } while(0)

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base( void ){}
    virtual void Print( void ) = 0;
    virtual void PrintInt( int i ) = 0;
};

class A : public Layer<A>, public Base
{
public:
    virtual void Print( void ) override
    {
        std::cout << "A Printing" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void PrintInt( int i ) override
    {
        std::cout << "A Printing " << i << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public Layer<B>, public Base
{
public:
    virtual void Print( void ) override
    {
        std::cout << "B Printing" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void PrintInt( int i ) override
    {
        std::cout << "B Printing " << i << std::endl;
    }
};

void PrintBase( Base* pBase )
{
    pBase->Print();
}

int main( void )
{
    LayerStack stack;

    PROMPT("Pushing A");
    stack.Push( std::make_shared<A>() );
    SHOW(stack.Size());

    PROMPT("Pushing B");
    stack.Push( std::make_shared<B>() );
    SHOW(stack.Size());

    PROMPT("Now Stack Looks like:");
    PROMPT("  [Top] B");
    PROMPT("  [Bottom] A");

    PROMPT("Query A Directly from the stack layer");
    std::shared_ptr<A> sptra;
    SHOW(sptra = stack.QueryLayer<A>());

    PROMPT("Query B Directly from the stack layer");
    std::shared_ptr<B> sptrb;
    SHOW(sptrb = stack.QueryLayer<B>());

    PROMPT("Call function in ascending order");
    stack.ForAscendingEach<Base>(PrintBase);

    PROMPT("Call function in descending order");
    stack.ForDescendingEach<Base>(PrintBase);

    PROMPT("Call member function in ascending order");
    stack.ForAscendingEach<Base>(&Base::PrintInt, 1);

    PROMPT("Call member function in descending order");
    stack.ForDescendingEach<Base>(&Base::PrintInt, 2);

    PROMPT("Accessing A from B should success(A is lower than B.(A is pushed eairlier) descending access is allowed)");
    SHOW(sptra = sptrb->GetLayer<A>());

    PROMPT("Accessing B from A should fail(B is higher than A.(B is pushed later) ascending access is prevented.)");
    SHOW(sptrb = sptra->GetLayer<B>());

    PROMPT("Popping A");
    stack.Pop();
    SHOW(stack.Size());

    PROMPT("Popping B");
    stack.Pop();
    SHOW(stack.Size());

    return 0;
} // int main( void )
```

**Output:**

> ```
>  * Pushing A
> stack.Size() : 1
>  * Pushing B
> stack.Size() : 2
>  * Now Stack Looks like:
>  *   [Top] B
>  *   [Bottom] A
>  * Query A Directly from the stack layer
> sptra = stack.QueryLayer<A>() : 01009074
>  * Query B Directly from the stack layer
> sptrb = stack.QueryLayer<B>() : 0100D544
>  * Call function in ascending order
> A Printing
> B Printing
>  * Call function in descending order
> B Printing
> A Printing
>  * Call member function in ascending order
> A Printing 1
> B Printing 1
>  * Call member function in descending order
> B Printing 2
> A Printing 2
>  * Accessing A from B should success(A is lower than B.(A is pushed eairlier) de
> scending access is allowed)
> sptra = sptrb->GetLayer<A>() : 01009074
>  * Accessing B from A should fail(B is higher than A.(B is pushed later) ascendi
> ng access is prevented.)
> sptrb = sptra->GetLayer<B>() : 00000000
>  * Popping A
> stack.Size() : 1
>  * Popping B
> stack.Size() : 0
> ```

Comment: Just a quick comment; you have declared your Singleton copy and copy-assignment operators as private and not implemented them to prevent copying; but the C++11 way to do this would be to write: `Singleton( const Singleton& ) = delete;`

Comment: Please remember to vote on any answers you've found helpful, now that you have sufficient rep.  Code Review is always in need of votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some minor things:

- Include guard names don't need an `_INCLUDE_GUARD` at the end.  They should not be confused with macros anyway, although you won't have very many of them in C++.
- Consider organizing your library `#include`s, such as alphabetically.  This will make it easier to keep track of all of them.
- Comments like `//Ctor` and `//Dtor` are noise since it's already obvious.  Comments shouldn't point out the obvious; they should provide useful information.
- Since your types are named in PascalCase, name your functions in camelCase or snake_case.  It's generally good to use separate naming types for these two things.
- All the `std::endl`s can be replaced with `"\n"`.  You don't need to flush the buffer so many times (which is what the former also does), and the latter will just output a newline.
- You don't need an explicit `return 0` at the end of `main()`.  Successful termination is already implied at this point, so the compiler will do this return for you here.
- You don't need a comments after a closing brace, *especially* at the end of `main()`.  It may be okay if you have many nested ones, but it's just clutter for others.
- Unlike in C, a `void` parameter is not needed for functions taking no arguments.

Comment: I thought that it was considered bad practice (if not undefined behavior) to assume an implicit return value from `main()`. Also, `std::endl` is a better idea than `"\n"` because it will handle line endings correctly on the unfortunate systems that use `"\r\n"` instead. I'd also recommend `#include`s being grouped by system, then library, then local, *then* sorted within each group.

Comment: @fluffy: Maybe in C, but this is a special case.  If something can fail (such as opening a file), then `main()` should return something else.  I don't see `"\r\n"` coming up too often, but in most cases, `std::endl` isn't particularly needed.  As for the `#include`s, I was referring to the libraries specifically, since more of them are used here.  But you're right that different `#include` types should be in a certain order.

Comment: You don't see `\r\n` coming up too often? You realize that Windows still has the largest desktop OS install base in the world, right? Not to mention that most textual network protocols use `\r\n` for their line endings...

Comment: @fluffy 1) The C++ standard guarantees that zero would be returned by default for the main function if you leave that out. 2) Completely false. Even on windows systems, std::endl appends a '\n'. The compiler is responsible for sorting out the line endings on its own. 3) Bad advice once again. Local headers, then libraries, and then platform-specific headers. Each group should then be sorted alphabetically.

Comment: @jliv902 Okay, thanks for the clarification on 1 and 2. However, 3 seems to just be a matter of taste. Can you back that up with any specific reasoning for why it should be local-first?

Comment: @fluffy: This will ensure that local headers are not exposed to other types (especially libraries) if this is unwanted.

Comment: @Jamal Okay, that's a pretty good reason.

Comment: @fluffy You should strive to make modular code and you want your headers to be independent of each other if possible. If you include library headers first for example, you may be covering up mistakes. For example, put `std::string s ;` into a sample header file with nothing else (no `#include <string>`). Then in your source file with `main`, put `#include <string>` and then `#include "header.h"`. Create a main function and the code will compile because it is a single translation unit. Hopefully it's clear that this is a mistake. (Will continue in another comment)

Comment: @fluffy You would want to put the library files second because they will usually have debugging code that will conflict with the debugging code of the platform-specific libraries.

Comment: 1 Just in case it duplicates its file name with others from different library. They may use different convention. 2 I usually add them when each time I need the utility, and forget about them. Never tried to think such way, nice point. 3 True. 4 Didn't know formatting had a name. I'll look them up later. 5 Tested on my machine, and noticed that even though I feed '\n' into stream, Visual C++ will span in into \r\n automatically. 6 Didn't know that, thanks 7 Maybe it was used too much. 7 I personally like it, as it makes it look clearly like a function prototype instead of function call.

Comment: @user2883715: Regarding #7, that doesn't quite make sense.  Function prototypes are used so that calling code is aware of the function to be called during compilation (but if `main()` is declared below every function, prototypes are not needed).  You're just adding the same function info at the end of each closing brace, and this really doesn't add anything.  This is not a good use of comments.

Answer (score 5):

I have a few things to add to what @Jamal already mentioned:

- If you want a class to be uncopyable, don't make its copy constructor and assignment operator `private`. Instead, mark them as [deleted functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5513881/1364752):

  ```
  Singleton( const Singleton& rhs ) = delete;
  Singleton& operator=( const Singleton& rhs ) = delete;
  ```

  The `= delete` is explicit by itself, so I guess that you can also remove the comments about the class not being copyable.
- I don't think that you will use `Singleton` as a base class for polymorphism (you won't create `Singleton*` instances to store derived class instances), so you don't have to make it destructor `virtual`. Generally speaking, [`virtual` destructors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/461203/1364752) are useful when you need to `delete` a instance via a base class pointer.
- I don't think that you need to specify what you use in each included header. While it might be useful for `<memory>` or `<algorithm>`, what you will use in `<vector>`, `<unordered_map>` and `<cassert>` is totally obvious.
- It might be a good idea to forget the old `typedef`s and use the brand new [type aliases](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) instead. Their advantages are multiple: the syntax is closer to a variable declaration and to a namespace alias, and it can be templated to create an alias template. Using type aliases will help you to write consistent code:

  ```
  using instance_type = Derived;
  ```
- This kind of "closing comment" is not really useful:

  ```
  } // class Layer : public LayerStack::LayerNode, public Singleton<Derived>
  ```

  A good indentation will provide all the information you need. Moreover, IDEs and code editors generally highlights matching braces, further reducing the need for this kind of comments. You shouldn't write too many comments that are somehow obvious or uneeded, for after a modification of the code, a comment may lie and a lying comment is worse than no comments at all.
- When a method does not modify the enclosing class, you should `const`-qualify it:

  ```
  size_type Size( void ) const
  {
      return m_layerVec.size();
  }
  ```

  There are many functions in your code that do not modify their classes and that ought to be `const`-qualified.

Comment: 1 Had no idea delete could be sued like that, thank you.
2 Indeed virtual destructor there was meaningless.. In fact, I just realized that Singleton class is not doing anything in this hierarchy...
3 This one is true, but I like to be consist.

Comment: 4 Didn't know using alias could replace typedef, thanks.
5 I do think this is useful if source is too long. Especially when I'm not looking at the code from IDE
6 I was almost forgetting about const qualification. Nice to have them.